# Mysql Laravel Complex query to sum item quantity

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5

I am trying to build complex query in laravel for making sum for item quantity.

I have total four tables used in this query. My main table Inventories table

Inventories

[image]

My datatable is displaying by looping on inventories table.

I have another table is composite item table, which contains bunch of multiple items.

Composite Inventories
[image]

composite item and inventory table has pivot table which is relation between inventory table & composite item. relations something like many to many.

Composite has inventories
[image]

Now individual items or composite item are added to purchased order table

Purchase order[image]

Purchase order table has one child table purchase order details which Contains item & composite items.

Purchase order details

[image]

In the purchase order details inventory_item field contains item or composite item name.

I need to get total quantity of item which has approved status in purchase order table.

For example inventory_item (item) = "stest2" (quantity="10"),
inventory_item (composite item) = "aa-buycomp" (quantity="2")

Now see setes2 item = 10 + composite item (stest2 quantity)
see stest2 item id in inventories table is "22"

Now check composite item "aa-buycomp" in composite item table it has id = "1"

Now see composite_inventorie_id = "1" & inventory_id="22" & type="purchase" in composite_has_inventories table which has quantity = "1"

I need to final sum of quantity = 10 + 1 = "11"

Please help to build laravel complex query.